# Getting data attribute of html element in react.js context

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

The CMS passes a variable as data-rest-url attribute to the React.js App:

```
<div id="reactjs-root" data-rest-url="http://my-ip-addess:8080/Rest-api-here">...</div>
```

If I add jQuery to my React.js App, then I can simply:

```
 componentWillMount() {
    const $reactRoot = $('#reactjs-root');
    const restUrl = $reactRoot.attr('data-rest-url');
 }
```

But adding jQuery just for this? How would you pass some variable from a CMS to your Single Page React App and read / parse / get it with react.js?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that. Plain vanilla JavaScript works fine.
`document.getElementById('reactjs-root').dataset.restUrl`.

Comment: @Fred Sure, but it's harder to read and more error-prone (browser quirks): In general, I prefer to use the [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Structural_patterns) jQuery which handles all edge cases.

Comment: With React you usually don't really have any need for jQuery so if all you want to do is get an attribute from an element then its much better to solve that using plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider passing your data attributes to your component as props instead of hard coding the root element ID within the component itself.

Rendering:

```
var rootElement = document.getElementById('reactjs-root');
ReactDOM.render(
  <YourComponent resturl={rootElement.getAttribute('data-rest-url')}></YourComponent>,
  rootElement
);
```

Within the component you can access the injected url:

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props.resturl)
}
```

This makes for a more reusable component that is decoupled from a specific element ID.

Comment: Ah, that's a slightly better approach even. Good idea.

Answer (score 5):

```
const reactRoot = document.getElementById('reactjs-root');
const restUrl = reactRoot.getAttribute('data-rest-url');
```

Also, avoid using `$` in your variable name. You're likely to run into a lot of libraries that conflict with the `$` you have used as a variable.

Comment: Instead of the `getAttribute` method, you can use the `dataset` property.