# Inline access of a custom attribute in React

Tags: reactjs

In React, is it possible to do smth like that:

```
<div className={ this.props.value === ??? ? 'foo' : '' } data-value="bar">
```

I'd like to put the value of `data-value` instead of `???`

**UPDATE**

just to explain why would I need this.

Let's say `this.props.value` is an array and I have many divs like this. Now I need to go and check if `this.props.value.contains([data-value])`.

If there is NO access to `data-value` I need to change the condition for each element: `this.props.value.contains('bar-1'), this.props.value.contains('bar-2'), this.props.value.contains('bar-3')`

Comment: from where will you get the value of `data-value`?

Comment: it's hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this using the `ref` functionality of react. [See](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Temp extends Component {
  state = {
    dataValue: ""
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getAttributeValue = element => {
    this.setState({ dataValue: element.dataset.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    const { dataValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.getAttributeValue}
        className={value === dataValue ? "foo" : ""}
        data-value="bar1"
      >
        {dataValue} Test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Temp;
```

For a working example take a look at : https://codesandbox.io/s/1qo6vxv8l3

The class is applied. It can be confirmed via the inspector.

**Although** I think that in your specific case you mention that the `data-value` will be hard coded so I don't see how

> I need to change the condition for each element

will be a pain. So probably doing

```
<div className={ this.props.value === {valuePassedAsProp} ? 'foo' : '' } data-value={valuePassedAsProp}>
```

might be simpler. I would recommend going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785185/4282901) answer for a possible approach.

Comment: I think this is it. Your answer has both the answer to might question and the suggestion of a better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and not needed because attribute value is available within same function scope as it's used:

```
<div className={ this.props.value === barVariable ? 'foo' : '' } data-value={barVariable}>
```

In case this is a common task, helper function can be created:

```
const classAndDataValue = (valueProp, value) => ({
  className: valueProp === value ? 'foo' : '',
  'data-value': value
});

...

<div {...classAndDataValue(this.props.value, 'bar')}>
```

The use of `data` attributes would be applicable to legacy jQuery but isn't suitable in modern JavaScript and React in particular. [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) helper can be used to conditionally construct class string. In case `this.props.value` is an array:

```
<div className={classnames({ 'foo': this.props.value.includes('bar') })}>
```

Comment: Actually, IMO it's needed. Let's say this.props.value is an array and I need to check if it contains data-value. And now I have N of divs like this. I'd need to go and check against each value

Comment: Then you can use it as `barVariable`, as the answer suggests. The thing you intended to do is ok in jQuery but not in modern JS,  `data` attribute is intended for interaction with non-React code. Is there real need for `data`? If you have problems applying the answer to your case, consider updating the question with your actual code.

Comment: Thanks. I have no problem with applying code. In the helper function that you've proviided `bar` is unknown. I'd just achive the same with  { this.props.value === 'bar' ? 'foo' : '' }

Comment: 'bar' is passed there as an argument, `value`. But in case this is too complicated, yes, using it directly is reasonable.